# action.sendKeys(body, Keys.CONTROL + "j") dosen't open the download page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write tests for Chrome. I need to open the download page at one point so I used:

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "j").build().perform();
```

but it does NOT open the page. 
then I added this line before it as I though it might work but it didn't:

```
WebElement body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//body[@id='body']")));
action.sendKeys(body, Keys.CONTROL + "j").build().perform();
```

The weird point is that

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a").build().perform();
```

Works!!

NOTE: I do not want to use Robot class as it will open the page on other browsers if the focus is not on the test target browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using like Below code, it is working perfectly at my end ...

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("j").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

I'd suggest not to go for chrome://downloads as this will not work in IE and FF but CTRL + j will work on all chrome, IE and FF.

Comment: Thanks, it worked properly, now the problem is that while the test is running, the focus should be on the test browser otherwise this line of code doesn't work, I mean, if I run the test and then go and click on other things (for example, if i start coding in my IDE while the test is running) it wont work. how to solve it?

Comment: I guess, that's the limitation of both Actions class and robot class, browser window should have focus at the time of operation. You may find a workaround in ChromeOptions by setting some chrome browser preferences...May I know what are you trying to accomplish on the chrome://downloads page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the key binding? 
You could just navigate to the URL `chrome://downloads/` ...

Edit: Ofc, this is not the ideal solution for cross-browser compability. But definitely a good workaround for chrome.

Comment: how can I get to `chrome://downloads/`