# action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("j").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform(); does not work if the test browser is not under focus of the OS

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write tests for Chrome. I need to open the download page at one point so I [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492102/action-sendkeysbody-keys-control-j-dosent-open-the-download-page/37494523#37494523) the code below:

```
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("j").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

and it works properly as long as the OS focus is on the test browser, I mean if I run the test and then go and click somewhere else (for example if I start coding in my IDE while the test running) this code wont work.

How can I bring the focus back to the test browser or any other way that this code works and download window is open on test browser?

The interesting point is that it works for:
`action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();` even if it's not focused!!!

Comment: what if you do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` right before that action chain?

Comment: @kirilS. I tried it but it didn't work :(

Comment: and simply navigating to downloads page, i.e. `driver.get("chrome://downloads/");` didn't work? or injecting link to `chrome://downloads/` to the page and clicking it. After all your main problem is usage of this fragile workaround with pressing keys...

Comment: @KirilS. thanks, now the issue is that I want to click on "CLEAR ALL" button at chrome://download page but whatever xpath I use it cannot find , what should I do?it

Comment: You are already there with focus, send tab key and " " (space)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to clear downloads, and you cannot just simply start another ChromeDriver with fresh state, you can try the following:

```
    driver.get("chrome://downloads/");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("chrome.send('clearAll');");
```